# Syntax for functions documentation

Tags: discussion, answers, formatting

I often see people *(myself included)* linking to a JavaScript function documentation with the format `Object#function`.

**Example:**  [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Is there a reason why we use `#`?

I've grown used to it, but I remember thinking `String.split` would be a more logic thing to write.

Comment: @MikeM. Is there a documentation about this rule somewhere ?

Comment: No clue. Actually, I just realized that you're asking about JavaScript, not Java, so I could be completely off-base here.

Comment: @MikeM. Aha, that explains it. (I saw it in the title of a Haskell question the other day, which felt really weird.)

Comment: Just a guess, `Foo.bar` might be confused with other uses of `.`, such as a package name, or nested class?

Comment: This is the syntax used in Java for referencing methods and fields in Javadoc's `{@link ...}` and `@see`, etc, maybe people copied it out of habit? It is done there - afaik - to disambiguate from packages, inner/nested classes, etc.

Comment: Who links to it that way? Not something i see very commonly, and i spend  alot of time in the js tag.

Comment: @KevinB I couldn't give you any name, it's just something I've seen many times, and something I reproduce too.